# Downloading a Bson Collection with mongodmp in mongocompass and kubernetes Databank

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodump, mongodb-compass

I am trying to backup a database from a kubernetes cluster to my computer as a bson file. I have connected my mongodb compass to the kubernetes cluster using port-forwarding. Can anyone help me with the command I need to download a particular Collection (450gb) from a databank to my desktop?

I've been trying for a while now but I cant seem to find the way around it.

In mongocompass there is unfortunately no way to download a collection as a bson file.
The port I have forwarded the kubernetes pod to is 27017.

Comment: all the commands are here. did you read the docs? https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/

Comment: ssh forwarding from your terminal https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example

Answer (score 1):

From the mongodb official docs:

> Run  [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongodump)  from the system command line, not the  [`mongo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo)  shell.

So, assuming you configured [Kubernetes Port Forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) on your **local machine** like this:

```
$ kubectl port-forward service/mongo 28015:27017
```

And you've got output similar to this:

```yaml
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:28015 -> 27017
Forwarding from [::1]:28015 -> 27017
```

You can now export data from mongodb using the following command:

```
$ mongodump --username root --port=28015 -p secretpassword
```

This will create a `dump` directory in the current working directory and export data there.

Also, to export only specific collection use the following option:

```
--collection=<collection>, -c=<collection>
```

> Specifies a collection to backup. If you do not specify a collection, this option copies all collections in the specified database or instance to the dump files.

You can check other available option [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/).